# Redirect a process output in a csv/excel file in bash script

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have written a script in bash which generates output of disk I/O performance and gives output in following format which i redirect to a text file.

```
2018-04-18-12-09-32
File Size 250KB
dir /opt/testfile
WRITE TEST ==> 116 MB/s
READ TEST (W/O CACHE) ==> 350 MB/s
READ TEST (WITH CACHE) ==> 657 MB/s
```

But i want it to generate this output in a .csv file with following table format extracting from text file.

```
Date-time              Filename (being tested)     Filesize     Test type                      Speed
2018-04-18-12-09-32    /opt/testfile               1MB          READ TEST (W/O CACHE)           350 MB/s
2018-04-18-12-09-32    /opt/testfile               1GB          Write TEST (W/O CACHE)          500 MB/s
```

I tried few things using awk, sed, cut but i am not able to generate the results.

Suggestions will be a great help.
Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: your input and output needs to be consistent to be of any use for the readers.  Your file size says 250KB, but the output shows 1MB and 1GB!  Where do they come from?

Comment: I have an array of 15 values which will run through the a for loop which will change the values each time loop runs.

Comment: Good to know but that doesn't mean your posted desired output doesn't need to contain values mapped from your posted sample input. How are we supposed to guess why only one READ TEST appears in your output or how the WRITE TEST value gets mapped from 116 in the input to 500 in the output, etc. or how text that was upper case in the input becomes camel case in the output, etc. If there's an algorithm for that mapping you need to tell us what it is at least.

Answer (score 1):

Although I've not fully understood your input file format without the complete set of input file and expected output, I've tried to make a best guess.  Assuming the input file name is "textfile", how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a datetimes
declare -A filesize
declare -A dir
declare -A testtype
declare -A speed

# extract parameters with regex from the input file
while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)$ ]]; then
        datetime="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        datetimes+=($datetime)
    elif [[ "$line" =~ ^File\ Size\ +([[:alnum:]]+)$ ]]; then
        filesize[$datetime]="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    elif [[ "$line" =~ ^dir\ +([^[:blank:]]+)$ ]]; then
        dir[$datetime]="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    elif [[ "$line" =~ ^(.*TEST.*)\ +==\>\ +([0-9]+.+)$ ]]; then
        test="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        testtype[$datetime]+="${test},"
        speed[$datetime,$test]="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
done < textfile

# report the results in csv format
printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "Date-time" "Filename (being tested)" "Filesize" "Test type" "Speed"
for d in ${datetimes[@]}; do
    test="${testtype[$d]}"
    ifs_b="$IFS"
    IFS=,
    for t in $test; do
        printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$d" "${dir[$d]}" "${filesize[$d]}" "$t" "${speed[$d,$t]}"
    done
    IFS="$ifs_b"
done
```

Sample of textfile modified from the original one:

```
2018-04-18-12-09-32
File Size 250KB
dir /opt/testfile
WRITE TEST ==> 116 MB/s
READ TEST (W/O CACHE) ==> 350 MB/s
READ TEST (WITH CACHE) ==> 657 MB/s
2018-04-19-01-23-45
File Size 1GB
dir /opt/testfile2
WRITE TEST ==> 120 MB/s
READ TEST (W/O CACHE) ==> 300 MB/s
READ TEST (WITH CACHE) ==> 600 MB/s
```

And the result will be:

```
Date-time,Filename (being tested),Filesize,Test type,Speed
2018-04-18-12-09-32,/opt/testfile,250KB,WRITE TEST,116 MB/s
2018-04-18-12-09-32,/opt/testfile,250KB,READ TEST (W/O CACHE),350 MB/s
2018-04-18-12-09-32,/opt/testfile,250KB,READ TEST (WITH CACHE),657 MB/s
2018-04-19-01-23-45,/opt/testfile2,1GB,WRITE TEST,120 MB/s
2018-04-19-01-23-45,/opt/testfile2,1GB,READ TEST (W/O CACHE),300 MB/s
2018-04-19-01-23-45,/opt/testfile2,1GB,READ TEST (WITH CACHE),600 MB/s
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but how do i print this on the screen and redirect to a .csv file in tabular format?  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Copy and paste the script above to a file, say "testscript", add the execute permissions by `chmod a+x testscript`, then execute it by saying `./testscript > result.csv`.  Then open the created csv file with an appropriate application.

Answer (score 1):

one liner with awk

```
echo "Date-time              Filename (being tested)     Filesize     Test type                      Speed";cat 1.txt | tr '\n' '|' | nawk -F"|" '/WRITE TEST/ {split($2,a," ");printf("%-22s%-29s%-13s%-30s%-10s\n",$1,substr($3,index($3," ")),a[3],substr($4,0,index($4,"=")-1),substr($4,index($4,">")+1))} /READ TEST \(W\/O CACHE\)/ {printf("%-22s%-29s%-13s%-30s%-10s\n",$1,substr($3,index($3," ")),a[3],substr($5,0,index($5,"=")-1),substr($5,index($5,">")+1))} /READ TEST \(WITH CACHE\)/ {printf("%-22s%-29s%-13s%-30s%-10s\n", $1,substr($3,index($3," ")),a[3],substr($6,0,index($6,"=")-1),substr($6,index($6,">")+1))}'
Date-time              Filename (being tested)     Filesize     Test type                      Speed
2018-04-18-12-09-32    /opt/testfile               250KB        WRITE TEST                     116 MB/s
2018-04-18-12-09-32    /opt/testfile               250KB        READ TEST (W/O CACHE)          350 MB/s
2018-04-18-12-09-32    /opt/testfile               250KB        READ TEST (WITH CACHE)         657 MB/s
```

Comment: Thanks Liu, but this is giving output in a single column. I need data divided in column and rows form.